# Devise and cancan examples working with ember js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

I use ember js + rails. I wanna to make user authorisation like Devise + Cancan in Rails. All i need is 2 roles : user and admin and i want to implement role and authentication controlling in ember js. All manuals that i found where very old. Mb you can give me some examples of app where such things are done? 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://say26.com/using-rails-devise-with-ember-js) blog post. It goes over how to use devise and emberjs. Not sure how the cancan would work on the client side, you'd have to come up with your own logic to do that.

Comment: I wrote that post and can't understand a little bit what fields he use in **UserSerializer**? **attributes :id** or something more?

Comment: The attributes could be anything you want. What you get is the current_user (if it exists) in json format.